# Use of "so" instead of "laut" or "zufolge"

Tags: translation

Take the following sentence as context:

> Dies sei auch ein Grund, warum die Gesamtkosten bei Anwendung von XXXX zumindest nicht viel höher sein dürften als bei Gabe einer Chemotherapie, so Duarte.

Are there any connotations or special meanings I should be aware of when translating the last clause of that sentence? It's not a construction I'm familiar with and want to ensure accuracy in case of any nuances.

Comment: Since you worry about nuances: "Gabe einer Chemotherapie" sounds a smidge weird to me.

Comment: Yeah it's not my sentence, just translating it for a pharma company.

Answer (score 8):

You could say this is short/an elliptic construction for "so (sagt) Duarte" or "so (behauptet) Duarte", which means the same as "laut Duarte".

Yet, the syntax would differ, as you would have to introduce the sentence with "laut Duarte", e.g. "Laut Duarte ist dies auch ein Grund, .."

when using laut, the subjunctive should not be used. Use the indicative instead - so e.g. "sei dies auch ein Grund" becomes "ist dies auch ein Grund" etc.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say, there's a slight difference:

One often finds the construction with "so" in newspapers.
It means, that Duarte actually said (less often wrote) the words before, or something *very* similar to it.

When using "laut" or "zufolge", it has to be something semantically equivalent, but can vary in choice of words.

Answer (score 0):

The most *literal* translation of "..., so Duarte" would be "..., according to Duarte".

I'd translate that sentence as

> This is another reason why the total cost of using XXX shouldn't be much higher than that of a chemotherapy, according to Duarte.

Comment: Acoording would be a literal translation for "laut" or "zufolge", but not for "so".